# Topology on space of full signatures in rough path theory

Tags: tensor-products, rough-path-theory, p-variation

In Theorem 3.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0260.pdf), the following result is formulated:

> Suppose $f:S_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function where $S_1$ is a compact subset of $S(\mathcal{V}^p(J,E))$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a linear functional $L \in T((E))^*$ such that for every $a \in S_1$,
>   $$
> |f(a)-L(a)| \leq \epsilon.
> $$

Here $\mathcal{V}^p(J,E)$ denotes the space of paths of finite $p$-variation from an interval $J$ to a Banach space $E$ (assume finite dimensional), and $S$ is the signature map defined as a collection of iterated Young integrals.

My question is, what is the topology on $S(\mathcal{V}^p(J,E))$? The proof uses the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, and I think that even requires $S_1$ to be a metric space, but since $S(\mathcal{V}^p(J,E))$ is a subset of the full tensor algebra $T((E))$ and is sort of infinite dimensional (even assuming $E$ is finite dimensional), I don't see what topology or metric it should have.

Or maybe this theorem should be interpreted as: whatever suitable topology we give this space, we can approximate continuous, real-valued functions by linear functionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E=\mathbb{R}^d$. Each $E^{\otimes n}= (\mathbb{R}^d)^{\otimes n}$ can be endowed with the usual distance, e.g. when $a^2,b^2 \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^{\otimes 2} = \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, we can define $$ d_2(a^2,b^2) = \max_{1\le i,j \le d} |a^2_{i,j}-b^2_{i,j}|. $$ Then for $a = (1,a^1,a^2,\ldots),b=(1,b^1,b^2,\ldots) \in T((E)) = \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty} E^{\otimes n}, $ $$ d(a,b) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n(a^n,b^n)}{2^n}$$ defines a natural distance between $a$ and $b$.

I'm not sure though if this is the topology the authors of the paper had in mind.

Comment: That's a good one. One small detail is that $T((E))$ is actually the closure of $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty E^{\otimes n}$, so in general its elements can grow increasingly large (don't need to have finite support). But for elements $a =S(X) \in S(\mathcal{V}^p(J,E)) \subset T((E))$ we have the bound $|a_n| \leq |X|_{1-var}^n/n!$, so on this space your metric is well-defined.

Comment: I know this is not the right place to post this, and this will get deleted soon. However, I am currently working on rough path theory; since this is a niche,  if anybody wants to message me I would be very grateful: martin.geller@maths.ox.ac.uk

Answer (score 0):

Usually in rough path theory, the norm on the space of full signature can be any thing, as long as it is "compatible". Lyons defined a set of properties for the norm to be qualified as "compatible". More details can be found in the book [St Flour Lecture Notes](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71285-5)

One example, which is quite standard, is demonstrated in the Definition 2.10 in  [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7871.pdf)